# Positioning images from array

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can somebody explain me how can I position images from array using css? I have them in one line at the top of the page, but I want position every of them manually like I can do with classes, e.g.

```
.twelfth {
    position:absolute; 
    top: 35%; 
    left: 75%;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Here is a code I have at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stils.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function random_imglink(select) {
            if (select > 5) {
            }
            var myimages = new Array();
            myimages[0] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[1] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[2] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[3] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[4] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[5] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[6] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[7] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[8] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[9] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[10] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[11] = "monalisa.jpg"
            myimages[12] = "monalisa.jpg"

            //specify corresponding links below
            var imagelinks = new Array()
            imagelinks[0] = "http://www.facebook.com"
            imagelinks[1] = "http://www.w3schools.com"
            imagelinks[2] = "http://www.microsoft.com"
            imagelinks[3] = "http://www.dynamicdrive.com"
            imagelinks[4] = "http://www.freewarejava.com"
            imagelinks[5] = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com"
            imagelinks[6] = "http://www.netscape.com"
            imagelinks[7] = "http://www.codepen.io"
            imagelinks[8] = "http://www.youtube.com"
            imagelinks[9] = "http://www.imdb.com"
            imagelinks[10] = "http://www.google.com"
            imagelinks[11] = "http://www.apple.com"
            imagelinks[12] = "http://www.skype.com"
            var size = myimages.length

            for (var i = 0; i < select; i++) {
                var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
                document.write('<a href=' + '"' + imagelinks[index] + '"' + '><img src="' + myimages[index] + '" border=0  width="10%"></a>');

                var tmp = myimages[index];
                myimages[index] = myimages[size - 1];
                myimages[size - 1] = tmp;

                tmp = imagelinks[index];
                imagelinks[index] = imagelinks[size - 1];
                imagelinks[size - 1] = tmp;
                --size;
            }
        }
        random_imglink(12);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

```
a:nth-child(12) {
   position:absolute; 
   top: 35%; 
   left: 75%;
   z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Just one problem- now pictures are not working as links. There are links, but they are on the same line as pictures and continues at blank space after pictures. The page has to fit in screen without using scrollbars, but because of the links it doesn't. Any suggestions here?

Comment: try adding '{ display: block }' to the a tag style

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of json objects like :

```
var images = new Array();
images.push({'name' : 'xyz.png', 'link' : 'http://example.com', 'left' : '', 'top' : ''});
```

Basically you can add any variable attribute you want to add. And then traverse through this array.